# Python Shipping Calculator Using IF Statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a Shipping calculator in python by using IF Statements.
The application should calculate the total cost of an order including shipping. I am stuck at a point where python just won't run my code at all. I have a feeling I'm close but I do not know what is wrong with what I'm inputting because python won't return any errors. please someone just steer me in the right direction.

Instructions:

> Create a program that calculates the total cost of an order including shipping.
>
> When your program is run it should ...
>
> 1. Print the name of the program "Shipping Calculator"
> 2. Prompt the user to type in the Cost of Items Ordered
> 3. If the user enters a number that’s less than zero, display an error message and give the user a chance to enter the number again.
>    (note: if you know loops/iterations, OK to use here, but if not, just a simple one-time check with an if statement will be OK here.)
>    For example: if the cost is less than zero, print an error message and then re-ask once for the input.
>
> Use the following table to calculate shipping cost:

| Cost of Items | Shipping cost |
| --- | --- |
| <30 | 5.95 |
| 30.00-49.99 | 7.95 |
| 50.00-74.99 | 9.95 |
| >75.00 | FREE |

> 4. Print the Shipping cost and Total Cost to ship the item
> 5. End the program with an exit greeting of your choice (e.g. Thank you for using our shipping calculator!)

Example  1:

```
=================
Shipping Calculator
=================
Cost of items ordered: 49.99

Shipping cost:                     7.95

Total cost:                          57.94

Thank you for using our shipping calculator!
```

Example 2:

```
=================
Shipping Calculator
=================
Cost of items ordered: -65.50

You must enter a positive number. Please try again.

Cost of items ordered: 65.50

Shipping cost:                   9.95

Total cost:                         75.45

Thank you for using our shipping calculator!
```

Here is the code I have written out so far:

```py
#Assignment shipping calculator
#Author: Name


def main():
    print("Shipping Calculator")
    subtotal = calc_subtotal()
    shipping = calc_shipping()
    total = calc_total()
    main()

def calc_subtotal():
    subtotal = float(input("Cost of Items Ordered: $"))
    if subtotal <= 0:
        print("You must enter a positive number. Please try again.")
        return subtotal

def calc_shipping():
    subtotal = calc_subtotal()
    shipping =  calc_shipping
    if subtotal >= 1 and subtotal <= 29.99:
        shipping = 5.95
        print("Shipping Cost: $5.95")
    if subtotal >= 30 and subtotal <= 49.99:
        shipping = 7.95
        print("Shipping Cost: $7.95")
    if subtotal >= 50 and subtotal <= 74.99:
        shipping = 9.95
        print("Shipping Cost: $9.95")
    if subtotal >= 75:
        shipping = 0
        print("Shipping Cost: Free")

def calc_total():
    total = calc_subtotal() + calc_shipping()
    print("Total Cost: ",total)
    print("Thank you for using our shipping calculator!")
```

Comment: For starters, the `main()` should be outside of the main function, so it should be at end of the program from where it will call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I will put the code here then explain all the changes I made (your original attempt was very close, just a few tweaks):

```
#Assignment shipping calculator
#Author: Name


def main():
  print("Shipping Calculator")
  subtotal = calc_subtotal()
  shipping = calc_shipping(subtotal)
  calc_total(subtotal,shipping)

def calc_subtotal():
    subtotal = float(input("Cost of Items Ordered: $"))
    while subtotal <= 0:
        print("You must enter a positive number. Please try again.")
        subtotal = float(input("Cost of Items Ordered: $"))
    return subtotal

def calc_shipping(subtotal):
    if subtotal >= 1 and subtotal <= 29.99:
        shipping = 5.95
        print("Shipping Cost: $5.95")
    if subtotal >= 30 and subtotal <= 49.99:
        shipping = 7.95
        print("Shipping Cost: $7.95")
    if subtotal >= 50 and subtotal <= 74.99:
        shipping = 9.95
        print("Shipping Cost: $9.95")
    if subtotal >= 75:
        shipping = 0
        print("Shipping Cost: Free")
    return shipping

def calc_total(subtotal,shipping):
    total = subtotal + shipping
    print("Total Cost: $" + str(round(total,2)))
    print("Thank you for using our shipping calculator!")

main()
```

1. As @Devang Sanghani mentioned, you should call your `main()` outside of your function so that it will run
2. For your `calc_subtotal()` function, use a while loop to keep taking in user input until given a valid number. Make sure you move your `return subtotal` outside of this loop so that it will only return it once this number is valid.
3. In your `calc_shipping()` function, make sure you take in `subtotal` as a parameter since you are using it in your function. Make sure you also return `shipping`.
4. Similarly, in your `calc_total()` function, take in both `subtotal` and `shipping` as parameters since they are used in your function.
5. Given these changes, update your `main()` function accordingly.

I hope these changes made sense! Please let me know if you need any further help or clarification :)

Comment: Also, `return shipping` should be added in the calc_shipping()

Comment: Oops did not add that in comments ty!

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it, It makes sense why it wasn't running I had to call main at the bottom of the function. Thank you for pointing out the other mistakes too, I made the changes and it runs good!

Comment: npnp im happy to help :))

Answer (score 0):

So there seem to be 2 errors:

1. You forgot to call the main function
2. You indented the return statement in `calc_subtotal()` so it returns the value only if the `subtotal <= 0`
   The correct code might be:

```
def main():
    print("Shipping Calculator")
    subtotal = calc_subtotal()
    shipping = calc_shipping()
    total = calc_total()

def calc_subtotal():
    subtotal = float(input("Cost of Items Ordered: $"))
    if subtotal <= 0:
        print("You must enter a positive number. Please try again.")
        calc_subtotal() # Re asking for the input in case of invalid input
    else:
        return subtotal # returning subtotal in case of valid input

def calc_shipping():
    subtotal = calc_subtotal()
    shipping =  calc_shipping
    if subtotal >= 0 and subtotal <= 29.99:
        shipping = 5.95
        print("Shipping Cost: $5.95")
    if subtotal >= 30 and subtotal <= 49.99:
        shipping = 7.95
        print("Shipping Cost: $7.95")
    if subtotal >= 50 and subtotal <= 74.99:
        shipping = 9.95
        print("Shipping Cost: $9.95")
    if subtotal >= 75:
        shipping = 0
        print("Shipping Cost: Free")

def calc_total():
    total = calc_subtotal() + calc_shipping()
    print("Total Cost: ",total)
    print("Thank you for using our shipping calculator!")
main() # Calling main
```

Comment: (off topic i love your gojo pfp haha)

Comment: @FirestarXYZ Thnx

Comment: remove the call to main() from main function. :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answers, also consider the case where the price can be a few cents, so this line should change:

```
if subtotal >= 0 and subtotal <= 29.99: # changed from 1 to 0
```